# Inserting into a void* depending on CIN type? Always get access exception for unsigned_char

Tags: c++

```
    if(menu_option==1) //INSERT
    {
        SDI::StoredData* temp = new SDI::StoredData();
        int pos = 0;
        void* val = 0;
        int type = 0;
        string input;

        std::cout << "\t\t2.4 Enter what type of data (0 = int, 1 = float, 2 = string): ";
        std::cin >> type;

        if(type==0)
        {
            cout << "\n\tSelect a value to enter: "; cin >> val;        
            cout <<"\n\tEnter the position to insert it: "; cin >> pos;
            temp->data = val;

        }
        else 
            if(type==1)
            {

            }
            else 
            {
                cout << "\n\tSelect a value to enter: "; cin >> input;


                //std::string *g = (std::string*)p;
                //std::string dd = *g;
                cout<<"\n\tEnter the position to insert it: "; cin >> pos;

            }

            temp->compareValue = 0; 
            void *vp = static_cast<void*>(new std::string(input));
            temp->data = &vp;
            temp->type = type;
            ARR.insert (temp,pos,true);
            arrPos++;
        }
```

Desperately trying to insert into my void* pointer array, works perfectly with INT values, but as soon as i try and specify a different type of array, for instance with strings, i attempt to cast the input string into a void pointer and pass it into the structure, which SEEMS to work when debugging, but then, as soon as i try to then output the list i get an exception for unsigned_char and seems to be NULL?

```
for(int i = 0; i<max; i++)
    {       
        if(data[i].data!= nullptr)
        {
            switch(data[i].type)
            {
            case 0:
                {
                int *p = (int*)data[i].data;
                std::cout<<"("<<i<<")"<<*p<<" => "; 
                logger.Log(1,"Data is of INT type","Array::getAllValues()");
                break;
                }
            case 1:
                {
                float *p = (float*)data[i].data;
                std::cout<<"("<<i<<")"<<*p<<" => ";
                logger.Log(1,"Data is of FLOAT type","Array::getAllValues()");
                break;
                }
            case 2:
                {
                std::string *p = (std::string*)data[i].data;

                std::cout<<"("<<i<<")"<<*p<<" => "; 
                logger.Log(1,"Data is of STRING type","Array::getAllValues()");
                break;
                }
            default:

                break;

            }
            logger.Log(1,"Data isnt null, printing value","Array::getAllValues()");

        }
        else
        {
            logger.Log(1,"value is null, printing NULL=>","Array::getAllValues()");
            std::cout<<"("<<i<<")"<<"NULL"<<" => "; 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem is these lines.

```
void *vp = static_cast<void*>(new std::string(input));
temp->data = &vp;
```

You are storing the address of a local variable somewhere and use it later.

But this code has several other serious problems.

e.g

```
cout << "\n\tSelect a value to enter: ";
cin >> val;
```

Please refer some good books on C++ and try to avoid pointers as much as possible. Use modern smart pointers, if at all that is necessary.

Comment: What can i do to fix it? It's what we are taught to use as part of the spec, i wish not to be doing it in the first place! aha.

Comment: Assuming this is C code, rather than C++, you could fix these two immediate bugs. Before the line "cin >> val;" in case 0, allocate an integer pointer with a new and use this pointer. For your original bug, just store like this "temp->data = vp;". But still your logic seems wrong to me. Especially the if conditions for string etc.